# Unable to sort jqGrid column with sorttype function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

Trying to sort a grid with custom sort. I am building jqgrid with dynamic columns and data. Everything works well except sorting of one of the column. I am using javax.json to build the json and I am using jqgrid 4.7.0. Here is the grid code:

```
var resultsGrid = $("#resultsGrid");
var url = "grid/GridDataController?action=runSearch&searchText="+getSearchText()+"&_ts"+$.now();
var csvUrl = "grid/GridDataController?action=downloadCsv&_ts"+$.now();
var gridPagerId="#resultsPager";

var drawSearchResultsGrid = function(colNames,colModel,data) {
    resultsGrid.disableSelection(); //disales highlioghting cells outside selection like ghosting.
    resultsGrid.jqGrid({
        url: url,
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        loadonce: true,
        mtype: "GET",
        height: 300,
        width: 700,
        colNames: colNames,
        colModel: colModel,
        datastr : data,
        rowNum: 100000,
        sortname: "invid",
        sortorder: "asc",
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        pager: gridPagerId, 
        pginput : false,
        pgbuttons : false,
        viewrecords : false,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        onSelectRow : function(id) {
            logMessage("row selected ["+id+"]");
        },
        loadComplete: function(data) {
            logMessage("load completed");
        },
        ondblClickRow : function(rowid) {
            logMessage("Double clicked");
            $(escapeColon("#contentForm:viewPropertiesButton")).click();
        }
    }); 
    // Set navigator with search enabled.
    resultsGrid.jqGrid('navGrid',gridPagerId,{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});

    // add custom button to export the data to excel
    resultsGrid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',gridPagerId,{
           caption:"Export", 
           onClickButton : function () { 
               resultsGrid.jqGrid('excelExport',{"url":csvUrl});
           } 
    });
}; //end drawResultGrid function

//get grid config...
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   data: "",
   dataType: "json",
    success: function(response)
    {
       if (response.result == "0")
       {
           logMessage("Drawing results grid...");
            drawSearchResultsGrid(response.colNames,response.colModel,response.data);
            resizeGrid();
           logMessage("Results grid drawing done.");
       }
       else
       {
           logMessage("Error : " + response.message);
           alert(response.message);
       }
    },
    error: function(x, e)
    {
         alert(x.readyState + " "+ x.status +" "+ e.msg);   
    }
});
```

Here is my dynamic colModel looks like:

```
  {
    "result":"0",
    "message":"",
    "data":{
    "records":18,
    "total":1,
    "page":"1",
    "rows":[ ]
    },
    "colNames":[
    "IP Address/Cidr",
    "Name",
    "IP Decimal",
    "Cidr"
    ],
    "colModel":[
    {
      "name":"adressCidr",
      "width":50,
      "sortable":true,
      "hidden":false,
      "sorttype":"function (cellValue,rowObject) {    console.log('sorting by ['+rowObject.ipDecimal+']');    return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);}"
    },
    {
      "name":"name",
      "width":50,
      "sortable":true,
      "hidden":false
    },
    {
      "name":"ipDecimal",
      "width":50,
      "sortable":true,
      "hidden":false,
      "sorttype":"int"
    },
    {
      "name":"cidr",
      "width":0,
      "sortable":false,
      "hidden":true
    }
]
  }
```

ipDecimal is a hidden column but I am displaying it for testing purpose. Requirement is first column 'addressCidr' is a string column but i want to sort it using hidden ipDecimal column. The function neither does show console.log message nor does any sorting properly. However, If i sort by ipDecimal with sorttype as 'int' by clicking on its header, it works fine. Only thing i can think of is the double quote around the sorttype function itself. Please let me know if you see any other issue here, or what is the best way to solve this case. Here is snippet where I build json function:

```
private JsonObjectBuilder createColumn(JsonBuilderFactory factory,
        String name,int width,boolean sortable,boolean hidden,boolean sorttype)
{
    JsonObjectBuilder column =this.createColumn(factory, name, width, sortable, hidden);
    StringBuilder fnBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

    //this is not generic but can easily be made one :(

    fnBuilder.append("function (cellValue,rowObject) {");
    fnBuilder.append("    console.log('sorting by ['+rowObject.ipDecimal+']');");
    fnBuilder.append("    return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);");
    fnBuilder.append("}");

    column.add("sorttype", fnBuilder.toString()); // this works, not sure why above function does not work :(
    return column;
}

private JsonObjectBuilder createColumn(JsonBuilderFactory factory,
        String name,int width,boolean sortable,boolean hidden)
{
    JsonObjectBuilder column;
    column = factory.createObjectBuilder();
    column.add("name", name);
    column.add("width", width);
    column.add("sortable", sortable);
    column.add("hidden", hidden);
    return column;
}
```

Data I used for testing is:

```
  IpAddressCidr ipDecimal
  5.1.0.0/24--83951616
  5.1.1.0/24--83951872
  5.1.2.0/24--83952128
  5.1.3.0/24--83952384
  5.1.4.0/24--83952640
  5.3.0.0/24--84082688
  5.9.2.0/24--84476416
  6.0.0.0/24--100663296
  6.0.1.0/24--100663552
  6.0.2.0/24--100663808
  6.0.3.0/24--100664064
  6.0.4.0/24--100664320
  6.0.5.0/24--100664576
  7.1.0.0/24--117506048
  7.1.1.0/24--117506304
  7.1.2.0/24--117506560
  7.1.3.0/24--117506816
  198.186.198.0/24--3334129152
```

But here is that I see
[image: Sorting randomly by custom sort function] Ip 198.186.198.0 should have appeared at the top as it has highest ipDecimal, but it gets pushed to the bottom.

To add more test information. If I remove enclosed double quotes, sort works fine, but not with it.
Following works:

```
 { name: "adressCidr", width:50, sortable: true,
            sorttype: function (cellValue,rowObject) {  console.log('sorting by ['+rowObject.ipDecimal+']');return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);}},
```

Following does not:

```
            { name: "adressCidr", width:50, sortable: true,
            sorttype: "function (cellValue,rowObject) {  console.log('sorting by ['+rowObject.ipDecimal+']');return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);}"},
```

Comment: You defined `sorttype` as string and not as function. It's the origin of your problem. I'd recommend you to use column templates. If you would have implementation problem I could write the answer.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I agree, but I am generating it dynamically using a json api please let me know what is the best to remove these double quotes. I am using java.json api to generate colModel. Am i left with perhaps changing grid.base.js to remove double quotes from sorttype function?

Comment: could you include test data which you use to fill the grid?

Comment: I tried with template as well, but unfortunately when template name is returned, json engine wraps template name in double quote and template does not work. It works when not enclosed. Am keeping at it until I find a solution.

Comment: I got it work with a hack. Not sure if this is good. I have template setup as     var ipAddressSortTemplate= {sorttype: function (cellValue,rowObject) 
   {  
    return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);
   }
 }
and in java code, i am adding temp variable addTemplate like this. column.add("addTemplate", "ipAddressSortTemplate").

Comment: And in the javascript, if a column has a template, i am adding template attribute with template name like           var template;
          for (var i=0; i<response.colModel.length; i++)
          {
           template=response.colModel[i].addTemplate;
           if (template)
           {
            
            logMessage("Template " + template);
            response.colModel[i].template=ipAddressSortTemplate;
            logMessage("Template " + response.colModel[i].template);
           }
          }

Comment: The value of `template` can be string and not only object in version 4.7. See my answer. It makes the solution really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of your problem is the usage of `sorttype` which you defines as string instead of function:

```
{
    "name":"adressCidr",
    "width":50,
    "sortable":true,
    "hidden":false,
    "sorttype":"function (cellValue,rowObject) {    console.log('sorting by ['+rowObject.ipDecimal+']');    return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal,10);}"
}
```

You use jqGrid 4.7 which contains new feature which I suggested (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/631)). So you can include the code like

```
$.extend($.jgrid, {
    cmTemplate: {
        myIpAddress: {
            sorttype: function (cellValue, rowObject) {
                console.log('sorting by [' + rowObject.ipDecimal + ']');
                return parseInt(rowObject.ipDecimal, 10);
            },
            width: 50
        }
    }
});
```

Now you can change the data returned from the server to

```
{
    "name":"adressCidr",
    "sortable":true,
    "hidden":false,
    "template":"myIpAddress"
}
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks Oleg. Now, that is much cleaner than my hack fix :-). Thanks again.